# how to modify list of actual variables in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to do the same thing to a list of objects. I can call a function on all 3 of them like:

```
x = double(x)
y = double(y)
z = double(z)
```

but even by pre-modern standards this seems hideous. I do

```
In [4]: z = 0

In [5]: x = 0

In [6]: y = 0

In [7]: items = [x, y, z]

In [8]: for item in items:
   ...:     item = 5
   ...:     

In [9]: print(x)

0
```

and no dice. How do you operate on a list of variables, I'm reading getattr and it doesn't seem to work for me

I want to iterate over x, y, and z in this case, and set them all equal to 5 in two lines of code- the for item in items, and then modify each item

For now, I get odd behavior, like all items are directly equal to each other:

```
In [11]: for item in items:
    print item is x
   ....:     
True
True
True


In [12]: for item in items:
    print item is y
   ....:     
True
True
True
```

I don't actually want a list, I want them to stay in memory with the same name so I can immediately do:

```
return {'income': income, 'ex_date': exdate, ...}
```

I didn't give enough info, but here is the goal, all 4 will have to be handled separately:

```
    total_income = self.get_total_income(portfolio_id)
    short_term = get_short_term(distros, 'ST')
    long_term = get_lt(distros, 'LT')
    total_distributions = self.get_totals(portfolio_id)
    items = [total_income, short_term, long_term, total_distributions]
    for item in items:
        do the same thing
    return {'total_income': total_income, 'short_term': short_term, 'long_term': long_term, 'total_distributions': total_distributions}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: have you read about list comprehensions?

Comment: ya, I used a few yesterday. I don't actually want a list though, I want them to stay in memory with the same name

Comment: They're all the same object in this case because you're using simple integers. Python will only generate a single object for a particular small integer value, and assign multiple names to it as necessary. If you were to do, for example, `x += 2`, it would assign `x` to the `7` object and leave `y` and `z` alone, just like you would expect.

Comment: It might help to see it this way: there are no variables in Python, only names and objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your loop is that all you do is assign 5 to the name `item`, but never do anything to the original list.

To modify a list (or, more precise, get a new list of modified values) you can either use a list comprehension or   `map` a function to all elements of a list.

```
>>> items = [0, 0, 0]
>>> [float(x) for x in items]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>> map(float, items)
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Another example:

```
>>> items = [1,2,3]
>>> [x*10 for x in items]
[10, 20, 30]
>>> map(str, items)
['1', '2', '3']
```

*edit* in response to your comment on the question:

> ya, I used a few yesterday. I don't actually want a list though, I want them to stay in memory with the same name

In that case, use a dictionary as your data structure instead of n lone variables. Example:

```
>>> my_values = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':3}
>>> my_values['y']
2
```

You can modify all your values by a given rule with a dictionary comprehension.

```
>>> my_values = {key:value*2 for key, value in my_values.items()}
>>> my_values
{'y': 4, 'x': 2, 'z': 6}
```

Comment: yes this seems to understand my question and the best answer

Comment: I can start an empty dict, update with a new entry for each 4 so you can read it, then comprehension

Comment: Of course in Python3 you will need `list` the map result.

Comment: even better because the goal was to return `dict`. I may start relying on those dict comps for everything :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you even don't need to use list comprehensions. In your particular case this is enough:

```
 x = y = z = 5
```

Comment: I just clarified my problem after seeing how vague it was

Answer (score 2):

If you want your variables to stay in the memory with same names but with different values you can do:

```
[x, y, z] = [5 for _ in items]
```

or

```
[x, y, z] = [double(i) for i in items]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about that?

```
 x = 1
 y = 2
 z = 3
 l = [x, y, z]
 l = [i**2 for i in l]
 x, y, z = l

 print(x, y, z)
 1 4 9
```

Comment: well my 4 items are all different, I oversimplified it

Comment: Oh I see, you can unpack the list like tuple. Yes that looks clean

Answer (score 1):

> How do you operate on a list of variables

Generally speaking you don't. If you have values you want to operate on as a list then you store them in a list not in individual variables. Or you can store them as items in a dictionary, or attributes of an object, just don't put them in separate variables.

For the particular case you asked about you could do this:

```
x, y, z = map(double, [x, y, z])
```

or for your other example:

```
total_income = self.get_total_income(var)
short_term = get_short_term(var)
long_term = get_lt(var)
total_distributions = self.get_totals(var)
items = [total_income, short_term, long_term, total_distributions]
result = {
    'total_income': total_income,
    'short_term': short_term,
    'long_term': long_term,
    'total_distributions': total_distributions
}
# N.B. Using list(...) to avoid modifying the dict while iterating.
for key, value in list(result.items()):
    result[key] = do_something(value)
return result
```

Comment: map is very nice here to leave them untouched